# Get all pictures and related comments from a Facebook Group page

Tags: facebook

I need to get all picture and their related comments which has been made to a particular facebook group page. How can I achieve this through facebook api?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you just need to make a request to graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/feed

Example here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=173972555961507%2Ffeed

The Graph API is really easy to figure out. You have the base url (graph.facebook.com) and then you can make requests to any object on facebook (user, page, group, checkin, etc) by just calling graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID. It's all on the front page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: But this will return me all feeds.. I need only picture which has been shared with other group members.. loading all feed with eat more resource.. is there any alternate to get only images posted ?

Comment: You can call the /picture field and use the "since" and "until" filters to get only the most recent pictures.